# Removing mutations for D metaprogramming/compiletime array generation

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming, d, c++14, template-meta-programming

My plan is to write a mutation-less code in D-language so that my values are available by runtime. Someone spoke to me about loop-unrolling and compile time code generation but I have no clear idea how to do that. I have made the D-template below but it has no guarantee to be evaluated at compile-time because on the two assignment statements(mutations) . Advice would be greatly appreciated. Suggestions could be preferably in D or C++ without macros.

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import std.conv;

const char[] ALPHABET="ABFCDFRGHDSTHFG";
const string pattern="ABA";


I[C]  computeAtCompileTime(S ,C,I)( const S  pattern ){
  I[C] table1;

  const int size = to!int(pattern.length) ;//Length of the pattern to be matched

  foreach( c; ALPHABET){   //Initialise array
          table1[c] = size;
    }

  foreach(i; 0..size-1){
             table1[pattern[i]] = size -i-1;
  }
  return table1;
}
enum TableFromCompiler  = computeAtCompileTime!(const string ,char, int)(pattern);
void main(){

    // enum TableFromCompiler  = computeAtCompileTime!(const string ,char, int)(pattern);

     writeln(TableFromCompiler);

 }
```

Comment: Just write normal code in D. As long as doesn't do input/output it can be executed at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

```
import std.stdio;

immutable char[] ALPHABET = "ABFCDFRGHDSTHFG";

int[char] compute(in string pattern)
{
    int[char] table;

    foreach (c; ALPHABET) {
        table[c] = cast(int)pattern.length;
    }

    foreach (i, c; pattern) {
        table[c] = cast(int)(pattern.length - i - 1);
    }

    return table;
}

void main()
{
    enum table = compute("ABA");
    writeln(table);
}
```

Output:

```
['A':0, 'B':1, 'C':3, 'D':3, 'F':3, 'G':3, 'H':3, 'R':3, 'S':3, 'T':3]
```

[Code on dpaste](http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/057c330afa0b).

Comment: Not sure if it answers your question, though.

Comment: That sheds some insight,but my plan is to compare/benchmark a runtime and a compiletime implementation. So if I write yet another regular function, it wont help my comparison. I need pure runtime and pure compiletime.

Comment: @Walker `enum table = compute("ABA");` this executes `compute` at compile-time. There's no such thing as a "compile-time function".

Comment: @Walker How do you plan to measure the difference? Do you plan to measure compilation time?

Comment: @sigod , the idea is to have two versions of the compute()  function, one which produces the table at compilation phase and another which produces the same table at runtime. I will then use the functions to another function that needs the tables and calculate the time overhead in the runtime one since. The runtime one is expected to be slower than the compiletime one as the table will get calculated every-time the application runs.

Comment: Here is the idea :-
 
UseTableValues(){
    1.compute_compiletime()  //Table already known  
    2.Use Table()   
}
getduration()

UseTableValues(){
   1.compute_run_time()  //Table  not  known  and so computed on the fly.
    2.Use Table()   
}
get_duration()// expected to be grater than first one.

Comment: Please check http://pastebin.com/pi7pewhr , I had difficulty formating the pseudocode.

Comment: @Walker, simply use `enum` in first case. E.g. `enum table = compute(...)`. And use `auto` in second: `auto table = compute(...)`.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you do **NOT** use `enum table = compute(...)`. Instead use `static table = compute(...)`. The reason for this is that arrays and associative arrays have somewhat unintuitive behaviour when used with `enum`, so it's best to just avoid it and use `static` or `static const` instead.

Comment: @Meta, links to explanation?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790652/enum-vs-immutable-in-d. The top answer talks about arrays, but AAs have the same behaviour when used with `enum`. When it comes to arrays/AAs/objects, always prefer `immutable` over `enum`.

Comment: @Meta, interesting. Thanks.