# Functions that work at compile time and run time

Tags: d

Is it possible to have functions that work at compile time and run time?

I want to create a function that takes integers and floats in an arbitrary order and sum them up individually.

```
static template IsSame(T){
  static template As(alias t){
    enum As = is(T == typeof(t));
  }
}
template staticFold(alias Func, alias B,Ts...){
  static if(Ts.length == 0){
    alias staticFold = B;
  }
  else static if(Ts.length == 1){
    alias staticFold = Func!(B,Ts[0]);
  }
  else{
    alias staticFold = staticFold!(Func,Func!(B,Ts[0]),Ts[1..$]);
  }
}
template Sum(alias A, alias B){
  alias Sum = AliasSeq!(A + B);
}

template SumIntFloat(Ts...){
  alias IntSum   = staticFold!(Sum,0,Filter!(IsSame!int.As,Ts));
  alias FloatSum = staticFold!(Sum,0.0f,Filter!(IsSame!float.As,Ts));
}
```

Which works nicely, but it only seems to be working at compile time. What if I want to call this function at runtime?

```
void SumIntFloatV2(Ts...)(Ts ts){
  alias Ints = Filter!(IsSame!int.As,ts);
  foreach(i;Ints){
    writeln(i);
  }
}
```

This also works and prints all integers that are passed to the function.

But it fails if I try to use `staticFold`.

```
void SumIntFloatV3(Ts...)(Ts ts){
  alias Ints     = Filter!(IsSame!int.As,ts);
  alias IntSum   = staticFold!(Sum,0,Ints);
  writeln(Intsum);
}
```

Example function calls:

```
SumIntFloatV3!(1,1.0,2,3,2.0,3.0);
SumIntFloatV3!(1,1,2,3,1.0,2.0);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31781188/944911

Comment: What is the that calls these functions supposed to look like?

Comment: Added two example function calls

Comment: yeah, you can do that with an ordinary function. I'll edit an example into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just write an ordinary function. When called in a compile time context, it will be interpreted at compile time automatically.

```
struct Answer {
        int IntSum = 0;
        float FloatSum = 0.0;
}
Answer SumIntFloatV4(Ts...)(Ts ts) {
        Answer a;
        foreach(t; ts) {
                static if(is(typeof(t) == int))
                        a.IntSum += t;
                else static if(is(typeof(t) == float))
                        a.FloatSum += t;
        }

        return a;
}

void main() {
        // compile time
        pragma(msg, SumIntFloatV4(1,1.0,2,3,2.0,3.0));
        pragma(msg, SumIntFloatV4(1,1,2,3,1.0,2.0));
        // runtime
        import std.stdio;
        writeln(SumIntFloatV4(1,1.0,2,3,2.0,3.0));
        writeln(SumIntFloatV4(1,1,2,3,1.0,2.0));
}
```

Comment: I understand that you can evaluate most functions at compile time but that doesn't work in my case. I want to utilize D's type system to generate a function that can be called at runtime/compile time but with some niceties like unordered function arguments.

Answer (score 0):

While I am grateful for the answers, they were not quite what I was looking for.

```
B fold(F,B,Ts...)(F f,B init, Ts ts){
  static if(ts.length == 0){
    return init;
  }
  else{
    return fold(f,f(init,ts[0]),ts[1..$]);
  }
}
Tuple!(int,float) SumintFloatV3(Ts...)(Ts ts){
  int intSum = fold((int a, int b) => a + b,0,Filter!(IsSame!int.As,ts));
  float floatSum = fold((float a, float b) => a + b,0.0f,Filter!(IsSame!float.As,ts));
  return tuple(intSum,floatSum);
}
```

It is now possible to call it like this:

```
writeln(SumintFloatV3(1,2,3.0f,5.0f,3,4));
```